# Mysql- Select Query from two table

Tags: mysql

I have two table item_info and item_log tables are given below:

[image: Item_info]

[image: Item_log]

Now i need to search by 'like'  item_name and the result will show last row of any item_id like:

[image: Result]

Comment: Try a inner join on those two tables.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)

Comment: `item_log`.`item_id` field is not looking unique, then how to decide which rows will come from `item_log` table.

Comment: What do YOU want the result to contain? Joining the tables will get you results, but the logic to filter that result set has to come from your side.

Comment: i need last row of any item_id @Girish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem Solved

```
SELECT item_log.*,item_info.name
FROM (item_log)
JOIN item_infos ON item_log.item_id = item_infos.item_id
WHERE id IN (SELECT MAX( item_log.id )
FROM (item_log)
JOIN item_infos ON item_log.item_id = item_infos.item_id
WHERE item_name LIKE '%G%'
GROUP BY item_log.item_id
ORDER BY item_log.id desc)
AND item_name LIKE '%G%'
GROUP BY item_log.item_id
ORDER BY item_log.id desc
```

Answer (score 1):

can you try something like this:

SELECT `table1`.*, MAX( table1.id ) AS last_id,

`table2`.`table2.id`

FROM (`table1`)

JOIN `table2` ON `table1`.`table2.id` = `table2`.`table2.id`

WHERE `item_name` LIKE '%nameOfItem%'

GROUP BY `table1`.`table2.id`

ORDER BY `table1`.`id` desc

it's kinda same with my function, i have to retrieve recent message for every thread. so i have to join the tables and group it by message id, and in the descending order in which the message has sent.

basically, the logic is quite the same. let me know if it doesn't work

Comment: last_id correct but other information not match@user07192010

Comment: You can just modify it depending on your desired outputs

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM
  (SELECT 
    item_info.`item_name`,
    item_log.`item_id`,
    item_log.`id`,
    item_log.`item_barcode`,
    item_log.`buy_price` 
  FROM
    item_log,
    item_info 
  WHERE item_info.`item_id` = item_log.`item_id` 
  ORDER BY id DESC) AS i 
GROUP BY item_id ;




I think this is what you are expecting right ?
```

Answer (score 0):

**This may work for you:**

```
SELECT l.id,i.item_id,l.item_barcode,i.item_name,l.buy_price 
FROM item_info i 
LEFT JOIN item_log l  ON i.item_id=l.item_id 
WHERE  i.item_name LIKE '%G%'  
ORDER BY l.id desc
```